# Can I download Stack Overflow chat transcripts?

Tags: support, chat

I was in a chat that provided a lot of useful information and help. Now I would like to preserve that chat. I know it's on Stack Overflow, but I want to have it saved on my hard drive or printed out.

Is there any way to download a chat transcript from Stack Overflow?

PS: I know that I can view the transcript and possibly print/download each day separately. This chat went on for a while and I would like to just print/download it completely.

Comment: User script it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a JavaScript implementation to get the text. In order to run this open your developer tools in the chat window (by pressing F12) and go to "Console", then paste the code:

```
function scrape(limit){
    limit = limit || 10000;
    var messages = [];
    var last = $("div.message").last().attr("id").split("-").pop();
    function getMore(last){
        return Promise.resolve($.post("http://chat.stackoverflow.com/chats/17/events?before="+last+"&mode=Messages&msgCount=500", fkey()));
    }
    return getMore(last).then(function add(newMessages){
        messages = messages.concat(newMessages.events.map(function(el){ 
            return el.user_name + " :  " + el.content; 
        }));
        console.log("So far", messages.length, "messages");
        if(messages.length >= limit) return;
        if(newMessages.events.length === 500) 
            return getMore(newMessages.events[499].message_id).then(add);
    }).then(function(){
        console.log(messages.join("\n"));
        return messages;
    });
}
```

To run it simply tell it how many posts you want to fetch:

```
scrape(1000); // get last 1000 messages
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I think it may need a throttle to avoid getting in trouble with SE for too many requests in a short time frame.

Comment: Yes, I did. Stack Overflow will throttle it for you after about 20 requests to one per 4-5 seconds- it's "trusted" since I'm using the user credentials here rather than public scraping and it doesn't require as much effort from the servers since I'm using the JSON API and not rendered HTML pages. It's also serial (and not parallel).

Comment: Just tried it with 100000 messages, works just fine :)

Comment: Looks like it took 5 minutes :P That is good that it throttles, because it would be a shame to accidentally get banned for something simple. I think the recursive ajax json approach is a good way to do this and it is nice that SE automatically throttles the round trip.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Its working very well (thank you) but Im not getting the chat for the room I am in, Its giving me some other room (One with you in it actually). -- The room I'm trying to scrape is "Frozen" since the chat was a little while ago. Could that effect it?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum could you address my last comment?

Comment: @huddie96 in this line:         `return Promise.resolve($.post("http://chat.stackoverflow.com/chats/17/events?before="+last+"&mode=Messages&msgCount=500", fkey()));`
 change to the room you're interested in.

Comment: Do you have an update for this with the new URL for the chat?

Answer (score 19):

There is no official api for chat.

I wrote a transcript parser for the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).  We use it to record meetings; you can see it in action [here](http://sopython.com/transcript/3/winter-2015-general-meeting/).  The code is a bit scattered, the relevant portions are [here](https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site/blob/1.4.5/sopy/transcript/parser.py#L90) and [here](https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site/blob/1.4.5/sopy/se_data/models/chat.py#L27).

The individual message code contains my opinion of the wonderful world of "friendly" timestamp parsing without an api.

```python
def html_load(cls, element, room_id, ts_date=None, update=True):
    """Create a message by id and update it from scraped HTML.
    :param element: message element from Beautiful Soup
    :param room_id: needed for fetching "see full text" messages
    :param ts_date: date parsed from page containing message.  If None, the timestamps are assumed to have the full date, filling in missing fields with today's date.
    :return: instance
    """

    id = int(id_re.search(element['id']).group(1))
    o = cls.get_unique(id=id)

    if not update and o.ts is not None:
        return o

    o.room_id = room_id

    user_url = element.find_previous('div', class_='signature').find('a')['href']
    # don't try to re-cache existing users, since they may be loaded for multiple messages
    o.user = SEUser.se_load(ident=user_url, update=False)

    # Yam it, these are the dumbest timestamps ever.
    # Not every message in the transcript has a timestamp, so we just give all those messages the closest previous timestamp.
    # A timestamp can be:
    # hour:minute period, in which case you need the timestamp from the transcript page, or the current day if this is the starred message list
    # yst hour:minute period, in which case subtract one day
    # weekday hour:minute period, in which case treat today as the last day of the week to calculate and subtract an offset
    # month day hour:minute period, in which case you need to get the year from the transcript or the current day
    # month day 'year hour:minute period, hooray, the only thing wrong with this is the 2 digit year!
    # I know they have the full, seconds resolution, timestamp somewhere, because you can see it when hovering the timestamp in the recently starred list

    # if this is the transcript, the day was parsed and passed in, otherwise it's the chatroom and we start with the current date
    ts_date = ts_date if ts_date is not None else datetime.utcnow().date()
    # find the closest previous timestamp and parse it with a crazy regex to handle all the cases
    ts_data = ts_re.search(element.find_previous('div', class_='timestamp').string).groupdict()
    # at least there's always a time, instead of "5 minutes ago"
    hour = int(ts_data['hour'])
    minute = int(ts_data['minute'])

    if ts_data['month'] is not None:
        # there was a month, so this will replace the start date
        # if there's a year, use strptime to handle 2-digit years as sanely as possible
        # otherwise, use the date we started with to get the year
        year = datetime.strptime(ts_data['year'], '%y').year if ts_data['year'] is not None else ts_date.year
        # get a month's number by name
        month = months.index(ts_data['month'])
        day = int(ts_data['day'])
        # build the new date
        ts_date = date(year, month, day)
    elif ts_data['weekday'] is not None:
        # instead of the date, we got a day of the week in the starred list
        if ts_data['weekday'] == 'yst':
            # or even dumber, we got "yesterday"
            offset = timedelta(-1)
        else:
            # to figure out the offset for a given day relative to the current day
            # remember the days of the week start on monday and are zero based
            # go back 6 days
            # get the number for the day of the week
            # get the number for the current day of the week, treat that as the last day of the week by subtracting from 6
            # add the last day offset to the normal day number, wrapping around if we overflow the week
            offset = timedelta(-6 + ((days.index(ts_data['weekday']) + (6 - ts_date.weekday())) % 7))

        # modify today's date with the offset
        ts_date += offset

    if ts_data['period'] == 'AM' and hour == 12:
        # 12 AM is actually 0 in 24 hour time
        hour = 0
    elif ts_data['period'] == 'PM' and hour != 12:
        # hours after 12 PM are shifted up 12
        hour += 12

    # build a utc timestamp from the date and the time
    o.ts = datetime.combine(ts_date, time(hour, minute))

    if element.find(class_='partial') is not None:
        # this is a "see full text" message, load the full unrendered message
        o.content = requests.get(full_text_url.format(room_id, id)).text
        o.rendered = False
    else:
        # normal full message
        o.content = element.find('div', class_='content').decode_contents().strip()
        o.rendered = True

    stars_elem = element.find('span', class_='stars')
    o.stars = int(stars_elem.find('span', class_='times').string or 0) if stars_elem is not None else 0

    return o
```

A bunch of us asked for a chat api during the annual survey.  SE devs, hear our cries for help. :(