# Can I save or export all starred messages of a (frozen) chat room?

Tags: discussion, support, chat, chat-stars

Recently, one of the most helpful and active chat room named **[The Great Gujarati Android Developers Ever!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93330/the-great-gujarati-android-developers-ever?)** has been frozen, because of [this request on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263092/disallow-languages-other-than-english-in-chat). I don't mind, SO rules may be to talk in **English** only, but we all are Gujarati developers over there, so we were talking in Gujarati to easily solve problems. And because of that, a moderator has frozen the room. I don't know whether that room will ever be unfrozen or not.

By the way, the room has been active since the last 6 months. We have shared and starred so many helpful links in that room.

As I am happy to help, I want to save all the starred links and share them in my blog. Is there any specific way to save or export them?

Comment: Just to clarify: The room wasn't locked because you guys were speaking something other than English. It was locked because flags were raised in the room: _"If concerns are raised over the appropriateness of a room's conversation, then either the conversation or the entire room is subject to deletion."_ If a room can't be moderated because of it's language, It's at risk of being closed.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but maybe you can apply a user script to extract starred messages. Maybe you can adapt one of the scripts provided in [this Q&A](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289435/2675154).

Answer (score 3):

There's about 7 pages of starred messages in the "Stars" tab, on the room's [info page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/93330/the-great-gujarati-android-developers-ever?tab=stars).

There's no *"All starred messages"* page.

Comment: How can i get it one by one page.