# When does the Hot Meta Post Block get updated?

Tags: support, community-bulletin

Currently [one of my questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323257/save-or-export-all-the-starred-message-of-chat-group?cb=1) appears in [HOT META POSTS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), as it has a score of **five**, but the Hot Meta Posts block is displaying a score of **three**.

[image]

How much time is that block taking to update?

Comment: Why do you care? Your question is already on hot meta posts.

Comment: I have to care. I just wanna know. If page is refreshing then why that data is not refreshed.

Answer (score 8):

The list that comes up in hot meta posts is cached - we do not update it (and the votes on the posts that show up) in real time.

So, yes, the votes that show up there are stale - the cache is for 15 minutes.