# Should the meta question be removed from "HOT META POSTS" if it is deleted for any reason?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, community-bulletin

Following question is visible in "HOT META POSTS":
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370062/add-text-from-the-library-recommendation-close-reason-to-the-dont-ask-page?cb=1

When I click on that, it redirects to Page Not Found page:

> **Page Not Found**
>   This question was voluntarily removed by its author.
>
> Here are some similar questions that might be relevant:
>   ...
>   ...

I am sure the question will be automatically removed from "HOT META POSTS" shortly and also that there is no any great issue if it is being displayed there for some time.

I just though this might be a bug and decided to discuss first.

Should the meta question be **automatically and immediately** removed from "HOT META POSTS" if it is deleted for any reason? Is this a bug that it is not happening?

Comment: It's probably there because the list is [cached](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) for some time. The cache will expire in a bit and that link will disappear as it should. Invalidating cache is one of those things...

Comment: It is cached for 6 to 8 and you hope it is minutes, at best it is hours but we have seen cases where it took days ...

Comment: It should be [15 minutes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323281/578411) ...