# Is there a way to get a feed of starred message from all pages?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues

I got one link to get [a feed of starred messages](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/feeds/rooms/starred/93330) from [previously asked questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323257/can-i-save-or-export-all-starred-messages-of-a-frozen-chat-room), but it gives me only the latest starred messages on page 1.

URL for default page 1: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/93330/feed?tab=stars

URL for page page 2: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/93330/feed?tab=stars&page=2

As we know, that will change `&page=XX`, but I want to get it in the feed.

Will it be possible to get the feed **page by page** or **all at once**?

Comment: Close-voters note: the dupe target was posted by Pratik as well.

Comment: @Alex.K. Please don't bump old posts to the front page just to remove a "Thank you"